# my html is not loading in browser using codeigniter view

Tags: codeigniter

i have a view name admin_login.php.in that i included two files public_header.php and public_footer.php.
here is my

### admin_login.php

```
<?php include('public_header.php'); ?>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<?php include('public_footer.php'); ?>
```

i am getting both included files in my browser but h1 element is not loading in browser

Comment: first of all frnd please comment your include('public_header.php'); that line in your code than check it

Comment: when i commented include('public_header.php');but that file is still loading in to the browser

Comment: Hello, Can you please share the file location of "public_header.php" and "public_footer.php".

Comment: Thanks the problem is solved i have a same file in view my file is in folder so i confused with the file .

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views

Answer (score 1):

Instead of including the header and footer file in your view, I'd suggest the recommended way.

In your Controller load your views like

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('content');
$this->load->view('footer');
```

Create these partials in views directory and render with above statements.